# vue-styleguidist error when dependency contains a .vue file

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I'm generating documentation for a VueJS component using `vue-styleguidist`.

This normally works just fine, but in this case I get an error:

```
./node_modules/vue-awesome/components/Icon.vue
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
 <template>
   <svg version="1.1"
     :class="klass"

Learn how to add webpack loaders to your style guide:
https://github.com/vue-styleguidist/vue-styleguidist/blob/master/docs/Webpack.md
```

My config file for vue-styleguidist (styleguide.config.js) includes the default rules for loading webpack files:

```
const loaders = require('vue-webpack-loaders');

module.exports = {
  ...
  webpackConfig: {
    module: {
      loaders,
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
};
```

Other .vue files are loaded correctly, but not Icon.vue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the default webpack loading rule provided by vue-webpack-loaders specifically excludes mode_modules directory, but the npm module contains that Vue file Icon.vue.

```
{
    test: /\.vue$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: vueLoaderConfig
},
```

The solution is to add an extra rule to the default rules to specifically load that file under node_modules.

```
const loaders = require('vue-webpack-loaders');

var vueLoaderConfig = require('vue-webpack-loaders/lib/vue-loader.conf')
loaders.push({
  test: /vue-awesome\/components\/Icon\.vue$/,   <-- path to .vue file
  loader: 'vue-loader',
  options: vueLoaderConfig
})
```